# How to get sitecollection relative link in webpart content link?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a webpart and I want to reference a js file in the content link. But I don't want to hardcode the full absolute path. I want to use the relative url.
The js is located in the style library folder.

The problem is I can't find out how to use the relative path. I tried

```
../../Style Library/username.js
```

But then this breaks if I use this same link in a subsite. Because the number of `..` is changed. I want a link that will work from anywhere. I tried `~sitecollection/Style Library/username.js`

but SharePoint doesn't evaluate the `~` variable into the path. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: In situations like that I usually just edit out the hostname from the absolute URL.  So instead of `http:/ /server/sites/sitename/Style Library/etc.js` I just use `/sites/sitename/Style Library/etc.js`.

Comment: But then your assuming `/sites/` is there in any environment, but thats only specific to your environment. I want something that will work in any environment.

Comment: Yeah, it's a shame that the URL tokens don't work for that.

Answer (score 1):

Using JS define the URL as `_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/Style Library/username.js"`

Read more about the `_spPageContextInfo`:

- http://blah.winsmarts.com/2013-2-_sppagecontextinfo_is_your_new_best_friend.aspx
- http://sympmarc.com/2013/03/26/using-_sppagecontextinfo-to-determine-the-current-sharepoint-context-in-script/

Update:

If the JS should be referenced on the web part's properties and the `~sitecollection` doesn't seem to do the work, replace the `~` mark with `&#126;`.

Comment: It should rather be `_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl` as Style Library will most often be present in root site collection. So even if you are in a sub site the Url generated through `_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl` will be same.

Comment: But how do I use this in the web part content link?

Comment: @omega See my updated answer.